# How to change permissions to all files?

Tags: permissions

Say I want to give set `rw` permissions for `g` for all files in the current directory, how do I do it?

I tried

```
chmod 006 \;
chmod g=rw
```

I'm not sure what should I use to represent files.

Comment: Does [this help](http://superuser.com/questions/280994/give-write-permissions-to-multiple-users-on-a-folder-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

You can use wildcard characters, also called [globs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) or filename patterns. The character `*` stands for any character sequence, so `*` matches all files in the current directory. (Exception: files whose name begins with `.`, called [dot files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments), are not matched.) Thus:

```
chmod g=rw *
```

If you want to affect files in subdirectories as well, including the directories themselves (even the current directory), you can operate `chmod` in recursive mode, with the `-R` option.

```
chmod -R g=rw .
```